# Changinng in-game Armature Object's Armature Data

Tags: game-engine, armature

I'm my current game project my main character needs to transform into another character, i can easily change the mesh data from the gameObject, but i can't find any documentation about changing the Armature data for my Armature object.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about **Armature datablock**, it is similar as changing the mesh data for mesh object:

[image]

If you are talking about changing **Action Data** for armature, there are two places to go, depends on your actual need:

[image]

For BGE action, you may take the 2nd one.

**PS:** Action Data exchanging between armatures requires high similarity, in other words, same hierachy, same bone count, same bone names, etc. Otherwise it will not work as expected.